# Recover Lost NTFS Partition With Corrupted Boot Sector

Tags: ntfs, bootsector

Is there a way to recover a lost NTFS partition with a corrupted boot sector ?

The backup boot sector is also corrupted. I know that the NTFS partition used to start in sector `551585791`.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover your partition. In order to recover your partition, follow the instructions given in their [wiki](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).